# Count regex replaces (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

Is there a way to count the number of replacements a Regex.Replace call makes?

E.g. for `Regex.Replace("aaa", "a", "b");` I want to get the number 3 out (result is `"bbb"`); for `Regex.Replace("aaa", "(?<test>aa?)", "${test}b");` I want to get the number 2 out (result is `"aabab"`).

Ways I can think to do this:

1. Use a MatchEvaluator that increments a captured variable, doing the replacement manually
2. Get a MatchCollection and iterate it, doing the replacement manually and keeping a count
3. Search first and get a MatchCollection, get the count from that, then do a separate replace

Methods 1 and 2 require manual parsing of $ replacements, method 3 requires regex matching the string twice. Is there a better way.

Comment: This is for a simple command line utility that could get called with any regex search and replace patterns as command line arguments. So ideally would want a generic solution that doesn't assume knowledge of the pattern in advance. Really though this is for interest - what's the best way of doing this in .Net? It seems like the MatchEvaluator approach with manual parsing of $ replacements is the way forward, but it's a bit messy :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to both Chevex and Guffa. I started looking for a better way to get the results and found that there is a Result method on the Match class that does the substitution. That's the missing piece of the jigsaw. Example code below:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace regexrep
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
            int matchCount = 0;
            string newText = Regex.Replace(fileText, args[1],
                (match) =>
                {
                    matchCount++;
                    return match.Result(args[2]);
                });
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(args[0], newText);
            return matchCount;
        }
    }
}
```

With a file test.txt containing aaa, the command line `regexrep test.txt "(?<test>aa?)" ${test}b` will set %errorlevel% to 2 and change the text to aabab.

Comment: (Match match) can be simplified to just the variable name "match" as the type is implied.

Comment: I was unaware of the Result() method on the match object. That is a nice quick and easy way to just execute some functionality on each match while still letting the Replace() do it's job. Good work Simon.

Comment: Other answers have my upvotes, but the key for me is the match.Result, so accepting my own answer for this. Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `MatchEvaluator` that runs for each replacement, that way you can count how many times it occurs:

```
int cnt = 0;
string result = Regex.Replace("aaa", "a", m => {
  cnt++;
  return "b";
});
```

The second case is trickier as you have to produce the same result as the replacement pattern would:

```
int cnt = 0;
string result = Regex.Replace("aaa", "(?<test>aa?)", m => {
  cnt++;
  return m.Groups["test"] + "b";
});
```

Comment: And here is the lambda equivalent to my answer :3

Comment: @Chevex: I took a little longer for me to answer, as I tested the code first. ;)

Comment: See my comment on Chevex's answer - this will only work if you know the patterns in advance. Otherwise you need to parse the regex replace string.

Comment: I had no need to test the code, I copied it directly from a project where it has been in use for months and added a count variable. Then I took your syntax with lambda and adapted my answer to use a lambda instead of a declared method. ;)

Comment: Also, I +1'd your answer after you posted it. So your snarky sarcasm is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it.

```
     int count = 0;
     string text = Regex.Replace(text,
          @"(((http|ftp|https):\/\/|www\.)[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)", //Example expression. This one captures URLs.
          match =>
          {
               string replacementValue = String.Format("<a href='{0}'>{0}</a>", match.Value);
               count++;
               return replacementValue;
          });
```

<strike>I am not on my dev computer so I can't do it right now, but I am going to experiment later and see if there is a way to do this with lambda expressions instead of declaring the method IncrementCount() just to increment an int.</strike>

**EDIT** modified to use a lambda expression instead of declaring another method.

**EDIT2** If you don't know the pattern in advance, you can still get all the groupings (The $ groups you refer to) within the match object as they are included as a GroupCollection. Like so:

```
     int count = 0;
     string text = Regex.Replace(text,
          @"(((http|ftp|https):\/\/|www\.)[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)", //Example expression. This one captures URLs.
          match =>
          {
               string replacementValue = String.Format("<a href='{0}'>{0}</a>", match.Value);
               count++;
               foreach (Group g in match.Groups)
               {
                    g.Value; //Do stuff with g.Value
               }
               return replacementValue;
          });
```

Comment: This will work (thank you!), but is basically my method 1. To make it work for generic input and output, you'd need to parse the ${test} in the replacement, so we need something more complicated (the "manual parsing of $ replacements" I refer to).

Comment: Match objects include the $ groups as a GroupCollection attached to them. If you don't know the expression beforehand and don't know how many groups would be included, then loop through the group collection like my EDIT2 does. I don't do anything with the group value in the answer but it should be easy for you to see how you could.