# In C#, is there any way to tell how many replacements Regex.Replace made?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count regex replaces (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994225/count-regex-replaces-c)

Is there any way to tell how many replacements a `Regex.Replace(...)` call makes?

Comment: Related [**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4994225/1577396)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [Regex.Replace Method (String, String, MatchEvaluator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) overload and establish a count with your custom `MatchEvaluator`.

You can always do this like so:

```
int count = 0;
string newStr = Regex.Replace(origStr, regexStr, m => { count++; return "replacement"; });
```

Comment: +1 This is the simplest option, also the idiomatic one in javascript

Answer (score 3):

You [could do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx)

```
Regex.Matches(...).Count;
```

first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) of `Regex.Replace` method:

```
public string Replace(
    string input,
    MatchEvaluator evaluator
)

public static string evaluator(Match match)
{
    // handle matches count here
}
```