# How to get number of matches from Regex.Replace

Tags: c#, .net

I want to do a regex replace in C# dot net, and I want to know how many replacements were made. What is the best way?

The best I can do now is to look at the before/after to see if anything changed

```
var a = "gooodbaaad";
var b = Regex.Replace(a,"[oa]","x");
if (a != b) Debug.Write("changed");
```

but this seems rather indirect and not accurate in all cases.

Comment: This doesn't look like a Regex replace from the code.  Nothing will ever happen with the code above.

Comment: You could create a `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`, then call `yourRegex.Replace(string input, MatchEvaluator evaluator)` and have your evaluator keep a count.  Edit: this is basically what @NicholasCarey suggests in his answer.

Comment: sorry, now I fixed the question so it uses Regex

Comment: Are you looking for Regex.Matches?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994225/count-regex-replaces-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use another overload of Regex.Replace [with MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;           

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int count = 0;
        var b = Regex.Replace("gooodbaaad", "[oa]", m=> { count++; return "x"; });

        Console.WriteLine(b);
        Console.WriteLine(count);           
    }
}
```

[demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wVUBdW)

Comment: Thanks. It was not obvious to me from MSDN that I could use lambda in this context. Now I know!

Comment: @JohnHenckel, fine! `MatchEvaluator` is a delegate, so you can use a lambda expression

Comment: Technically your answer is not complete.  You should have `return m.Result("x")` in case the string `"x"` contains `$1` or stuff like that.

Comment: @JohnHenckel, thank you for comment. i can't agree that it is not correct, since there are no captured groups here

Answer (score 5):

Try something like the following. It transforms all sequences of 1 or more word characters to the literal text `{word}` and counts the replacements. So, the source text

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
```

would be transformed to

```
{word} {word} {word} {word} {word} {word} {word} {word} {word}.
```

And at the end of the operation, the variable `cnt` has the value `9`.

```
Regex pattern      = new Regex( @"\w+" ) ;
string source      = GetMeMySourceData() ;
int    cnt         = 0 ;
string transformed = pattern.Replace( source , m => {
    ++cnt ;
    return "{word}" ;
  });
```

The power of closures.