# Getting a count of "find" from multiple .txt files

Tags: vb.net

I am currently running a find and replace through hundreds of .txt files at a time. I am looking for a way to pull a count of the number of finds for my value. 
Here is the code I am currently running, hoping to be able to add to or modify this code.

```
Dim flatfiles As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\DATA\TEST\", "*.txt").Where(Function(x) File.ReadAllText(x).Contains("Bob")).ToArray
    For Each f As String In flatfiles
        Dim contents As String = File.ReadAllText(f)
        File.WriteAllText(f, contents.Replace("Bob", "Bill"))
    Next
```

Comment: Perhaps use a regex replace, then its easy to count & replace and it can be instructed to replace words only avoiding *bobby* becoming *billby*, see [Count regex replaces (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994225/count-regex-replaces-c)

Comment: I sure hope these files are not big, current approach is simple and basic, but it works. The question is, is it the right approach? Look into ***Trie***,are capable of storing a sequence of values in such a way that tracing the path from the root to any node yields a valid subset of that sequence...

Answer (score -1):

One (inefficient) way to do this would be to include a counter outside of the `For Each` loop (`Dim itemsFound as Integer = 0`), then increment it by the count of `find` in each file, using something like:

`itemsFound = itemsFound + (Regex.Split(contents, find).Length - 1)`

`Regex.Split` splits the string up whenever it finds `find`, which means the count you're looking for is one less than the number of items in the list.

I would say as well, that you're calling `File.ReadAllText` twice in your code, so you could improve it by getting rid of the `Where` code, and just check in your `For each` loop (seeing as you're now counting the number of instances in the file  anyway, it's easy enough to check for 0 occurrences). Alternatively, you could replace the `.Where` code to store the contents of the file in an array rather than the name of the files (although this can be dangerous if the files are large); or you could even just do it all in Linq if you want some obfuscated code...

Comment: I am looking into this now and will get back shortly. I would not say that this needs to be efficient, just work. Thanks for suggestion, touch back soon..

Comment: would whoever downvoted please explain why, so I can improve my answer?