# how do i count the replaced char in a string?

Tags: vba, vb.net

[so i put the string like "hello world" and want to change "l" to "a" then i need to count the no. of changed letters how do i count the change letters only? help pls[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu1PF.jpg

Comment: Please show your efforts to solve your problem. Do not ask simply to write code for you. (And vba is not VB.NET, decide which language are you using)

Comment: The obvious thing to do is to count the replaceable characters before doing the replacement. I'm not going to write your code for you though.

Comment: Where is your attempt at coding this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count regex replaces (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994225/count-regex-replaces-c).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a possible solution would be computing the length difference between the input string and the same one with find string substituted with "":

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    newStringTB.Text = inputTB.Text.Replace(findTB.Text, replaceTB.Text)
    noOfReplacedTB.Text = Len(inputTB.Text) - Len(Replace(inputTB.Text, findTB.Text, ""))
End Sub
```

just change:

- "Button1" to your actual command button name
- "newStringTB", "findTB", "replaceTB" and "noOfReplacedTB" to your actual textboxes names